# Send an email based on the date in a CSV column

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking to read data from a column in my CSV file.
All of the data in this column are dates. (DD/MM/YYYY).
I want my program to read the Dates column, and if the date is within 3 days of the current date, I want to add variables to all of the values in that row.

Ex.

```
Date,Name,LaterDate
1/1/19,John Smith, 2/21/19
```

If I run my program on 2/19/2019, I want an email sent that says "John Smith's case is closing on "2/21/2019".

I understand how to send an email. The part that I get stuck on is:
Reading the CSV column specifically.
If the date is within 3 days,
Assign variables to the values in the ROW,
Use those variables to send a custom email.

I see a lot of "Use Pandas" but I might need the individual steps broken down.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you need to read all the values of the csv file and store it in a variable (`old_df`). Then you need to save all the dates in the Series (`dates`). Next we create an  empty DataFrame with the same columns. From here we create a simple for loop for each `date` in `dates` and it's index `i`. Turn date into a datetime object from the datetime library. Then we subtract amount of days between the current date and `date`. Take the absolute value of `days` so we always get a positive amount of days. Then add the index of that particular date in `old_df` to `new_df`.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

old_df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
dates = old_df['LaterDate']

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Name', 'LaterDate'])

for i, date in enumerate(dates):
    date = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%y')
    days = (datetime.now() - date).days
    if abs(days) <= 3:
        new_df = new_df.append(old_df.loc[i, :])

print(new_df)
```

Comment: It took a little modification, but I was able to get a sort of output.

However, right now my results are an ugly dataframe. I can read it, because it basically just pulls the names of the people that are within three days. (Among some other, ugly data.)

From the above, how would I make a "name" variable, that would return "John Smith" if the date in his row is within three days? That way I could add a:

print('The ' + name + ' case is closing soon.)

Comment: It depends on what you want `name` to be. If you want `name` to be a list of names that are within 3 days of the current date, just make a for loop that loops through each row of the `new_df` like so:`for i, row in new_df.iterrows():`. `names` should append `row['Name']`.